# HTMLバリデーションの開始タグ終了タグチェックを正規表現を使わずに実装したい

Tags: java, html, java8

今Java8で入力値のテキストに対して、HTMLバリデーションを実装しています。HTMLタグが入力されている際の開始タグ終了タグチェックです。たとえば`<table>aiueo`なら`</table>`がないのでエラー、`aiueo</table>`なら`<table>`がないのでエラー、`<table>aiueo</table>`ならエラーなしです。
終了タグが必要なタグは候補として出せているので、**シンプルに「開始タグ終了タグ」チェックのロジックを実装したいです。ただ正規表現は処理が重くなるので他の方法（例えばJavaのAPIのメソッドを使ったり）で実装したいです。**
ただしAPI側の実装なのであくまでJava側での実装になります。

わかる方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？アイデアやヒント、キッカケ、予想でも構いません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この記事と回答の紹介先あたりが参考になるかも。[How to validate HTML from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4392505/9014308), [Open Source HTML Parsers in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認してみたのですが、ちなみに閉じタグチェックに使えそうなのは回答者様はどれをイメージされていらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Comment: 済みません。検索結果の紹介だけなので、どれがどうとかは何も言えません。それぞれの人気とか更新状況と言ったものや内容そのものはそちらで調べてみてください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: かしこまりました